# Is there any detailed documentation for CoreNLP sentiment analysis?

Tags: stanford-nlp

I am investigating source code for stanford corenlp, especially in sentiment analysis. It is quite hard for me to understand the source code for sentiment part, without any documentation or testers. Anyone familiar with this part? Any guidance? I am not quite familiar with java yet.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there's not much documentation at the moment, and the code comments are pretty sparse. The best official documentation you will be able to get is [the original EMNLP 2013 paper](http://nlp.stanford.edu/~socherr/EMNLP2013_RNTN.pdf).

Of course, there is the [official Javadoc](http://www-nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/sentiment/SentimentModel.html) as well. There are also several tutorials online; see e.g. [a tutorial on the OpenShift blog](https://blog.openshift.com/day-20-stanford-corenlp-performing-sentiment-analysis-of-twitter-using-java/).